# ResultSet not positioned properly, I don't know where exactly to call next()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I've seen a lot questions like this, but none of them has an answer I need. 
I have created a prepared statement which will update my table Tickets. Now to the method buyTickets() I give parameters of CustomerId (knr), PerformanceId(aid) and No. of Ticekts to buy (anzTickets). I have to loop through my Query and for every ticket (number of wanted tickets - anzTickets) I have to call prepared Statement. But I got an error which says that ResultSet is not properly positioned. I'm not really sure where and how to call next() so that preparedStatement can be executed in each row? Here is my code :

```
 public void prepareStatements() throws SQLException {

    try {
        pstmt_updateTicket = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE Ticket SET kunde = ? WHERE tid = ? AND auffuehrung = ?");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Szenario1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This was my prepared statement and here is my buyTickets() method :

```
public double buyTickets(int knr, int aid, int anzTickets) throws Exception {
    double newgesamtpreis = 0;
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = pstmt_updateTicket;

    try {
        int anzT = anzTickets;
        int freiTickets = 0;
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT tid, count(tid) FROM Ticket WHERE kunde IS NULL GROUP BY tid;");

        if (anzT > freiTickets) {
            throw new Exception("Es gibt nicht so viele frei Tickets");
        } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < anzT; i++) {
                    pstmt.setInt(1, knr);
                    pstmt.setInt(2, rs.getInt(1));
                    pstmt.setInt(3, aid);
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                    rs.next();
                }

            }
            ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(preis) FROM Ticket WHERE kunde IS NOT NULL");
            newgesamtpreis = rs3.getDouble(1);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Szenario1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
        pstmt.close();
    }

    return newgesamtpreis;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering what you want to achieve with the check `if (anzT > freiTickets)`. (I'm assuming freiTickets means freeTickets). Right before that check you are setting `freiTickets` to 0. The way it is written, there are never free tickets...

Comment: I had a query before the first one which checks how many tickets are free. I deleted it, since I thought it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Side-note: If you are working in a larger company, or an international company, it is good practice (required even in most companies) to have everything in English: variable names, class names, documentation, table/column names etc. That would also make it easier for us to understand what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For questions like these it is important to post a [MCVE]. If you snip things out, make sure it doesn't change the behaviour of the function, otherwise people like me stop at that point to say that your function won't work correctly. If you do snip things like that out for the sake of being minimal, add a (code-)comment briefly explaining what you snipped out.

Comment: Beside note1 I think that this code is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. And I think that this If statement is not even necessary to understand the problem. If-else works just fine. The problem is resultSet

Answer (score 1):

When a ResultSet is first created it is positioned *before* the first row of data. To iterate over a ResultSet, you need to call ***first*** `rs.next()`.
rs.next gets you to the next row of your ResultSet :

- `rs.next()` returns `true` if it successfully retrieved the next row
- `rs.next()` returns `false` if the ResultSet doesn't have any more rows

So, when using `if (rs.next())` or `while (rs.next())`, it positions your ResultSet only if your ResultSet has another row to retrieve. It's just like it gave 2 methods `rs.hasNext()` and `rs.goNext()` in only one method.

Try **this** :

```
public double buyTickets(int knr, int aid, int anzTickets) throws Exception {
double newgesamtpreis = 0;
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
PreparedStatement pstmt = pstmt_updateTicket;

try {
    int anzT = anzTickets;
    int freiTickets = 0;
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT tid, count(tid) FROM Ticket WHERE kunde IS NULL GROUP BY tid;");

while(rs.next()){
    if (anzT > freiTickets) {
        throw new Exception("Es gibt nicht so viele frei Tickets");
    } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < anzT; i++) {
                pstmt.setInt(1, knr);
                pstmt.setInt(2, rs.getInt(1));
                pstmt.setInt(3, aid);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }

        }
        ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(preis) FROM Ticket WHERE kunde IS NOT NULL");
        if (rs3.next())
            newgesamtpreis = rs3.getDouble(1);
}

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Szenario1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
    stmt.close();
    pstmt.close();
}

return newgesamtpreis;
}
```

Or just call rs.next() every time before you iterate over your ResultSet

Comment: Please explain your answer, else it will not help future visitors to this site with similar problems.

Comment: Is this answer better ? Tried to explain it with simple words

Comment: Small error, you claim *"rs.next() returns true if your result set has no next value"*

Comment: Edited just now, sorry

Comment: So I should call rs.next() as first statement in for loop?